# Bootstrap show modal dynamically

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm adding a modal dynamically in JS by appending it to the body of my page but it is not showing when I call the following.

```
$('#modalId').modal('show');
```

Is this because the html is added dynamically? If so, how can I attach the modal show to an event?

here is my modal

```
<div id="modalId" class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            &times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">
            Detach Site</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>
            Are you sure you wish to detach the following Site Server from this site?</p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <strong id="server-delete-name"></strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
            Close</button>
        <button id="delete-siteserver" type="button" data-delete-id="" class="btn btn-danger">
            Detach</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am appending this modal to the body using $('body').append();

Comment: Can you explain more? How you are adding dynamic modal? in which event you are calling `modal`? Please post more code here.

Comment: Its being added dynamically as the modal html didnt exist at the time. I add the modal dynamically in js

Comment: Where you are calling ``$('#modalId').modal('show');`` ?

Comment: can u plz show on wat event u calling that modal??

Answer (score 4):

I use the modal like this. In the HTML of the page I load the skeleton of the modal:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in my ajax, I load the content of the modal. I mean this:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    Header content 
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
    Body content
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
     Footer content
</div>
```

And for every ajax call, I raplace the content of `<div class="modal-content">` with the new result.

I hope it helps you.