# Symfony 3 using the delete action in Twig

Tags: php, symfony

So I've copied the basic delete action from the [CRUD generator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html):

```
   /**
    * @Route("category/delete/{id}", name="category_delete")
    * @Method("DELETE")
    */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
        $category = $repository->find($id);

        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($category);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($category);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('category_index');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Category $category
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm(Category $category)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('category_delete', array('id' => $category->getId())))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->getForm()
            ;
    }
```

However, I'm not sure how to actually use the action itself. I want to do deletes in two places, and I'm not sure the correct way to do either:

1. Deletes in the edit action - How do I add a delete button to the form builder? I do I have to do it in the twig template itself?
2. Deletes in the index - I know how to call actions (e.g. `<a href="{{ path('category_edit', {'id': cat.id}) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>`), but this doesn't work with the delete action.

I've tried looking at the [Symfony demo application](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-demo/tree/master/app/Resources/views/admin/blog), but I still don't fully grasp how the delete action is meant to work - and I can't find anything in the docs.

Can someone provide a brief of explanation of how the delete action works in regard to 1 and 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delete script in `Symfony CRUD` works with a form submission. So, you have to render a form to show the delete button.

You may hesitate to render a form for each of the items in a list. Its also, not convenient to embed a from inside edit form.

With a bit of help from Bootstrap modal (confirm box for delete) and ajax submission, I came across this solution :

1. Make your `deleteAction` to support `GET` so that it can render the form when necessary.
2. Wherever you need delete link, give it as a link to the modal which in turn will load `deleteAction` controller to render a form in side the modal body. You can have your confirmation message in the modal as well.
3. When modal form submitted, handle your `deleteAction` script accordingly, and redirect.

**EDIT** : Added script for `Controller` and `Template`

```
/**
 * @Route("category/delete/{id}", name="category_delete")
 * @Method({"GET", "DELETE"})
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    /*
     * Check Permission.
     */
    $response = array(
        'success' => true,
        'message' => '',
        'html' => '',
    );

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Category');
    $category = $repository->find($id);

    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($category);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'DELETE') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->remove($category);
            $em->flush();

            // Get response ready as per your need.
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Deleted Successfully!';
        } else {
            $response['success'] = false;
            $response['message'] = 'Sorry category could not be deleted!';
        }
        return new JsonResponse($response);

        // In case you want to redirect.
        // $this->addFlash('notice', 'Deleted Successfully!');
        // return $this->redirectToRoute('category_index');
    }
    $render = $this->render(':category:delete_confirm.html.twig', array(
        'delete_form' => $form->createView(),
        'category' => $category,
    ));

    $response['html'] = $render->getContent();

    return new JsonResponse($response);
}
```

Twig HTML code to return Modal (I'm using UIKIT modal)

```
{{ form_start(delete_form) }}
<div class="uk-modal-header">
    <h3 class="uk-modal-title">Delete this Category?</h3>
</div>
<p>
    Are you sure you want to delete  '{{ category.name }}'?<br/>
    This cannot be undone.
</p>
<div class="uk-modal-footer uk-text-right">
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="md-btn md-btn-danger" title="Click to proceed!">
            <i class="uk-icon-trash"></i> Delete
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="md-btn md-btn-warning uk-modal-close">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_end(delete_form) }}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you could share some code that would be great, I'm not hugely familiar with Ajax.

Comment: Added script for Controller and Template. You can take care of JavaScript to render modal dynamically and submit form with the help of jQuery.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super informative. I'm having a little trouble figuring the html for the delete button itself, could you also add that?

Comment: Also, is your `createDeleteForm` method exactly the same as mine?

Comment: `createDeleteForm` is similar. Delete button attributes depends on how you call a dynamic bootstrap modal. I have a different script to handle all ajax modal in the application with UIKIT. Hence, button attributes are totally different and customised as per my script. Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19005603/1140358)  or google for dynamic boostrap modal.